# mongodb: remove subdocument with where clause that includes document & subdocument

Tags: mongodb

Here is my collection (workers):

```
"type" : "Manager",
"employees" : [{
    "name" : "bob"
    "id" : 101
    },{
    "name" : "phil"
    "id" : 102
    },{
    "name" : "bob"
    "id" : 103
    }]
```

First: this is **NOT an array** so $pullAll will not work or other array commands.  All I want to do is: (1) search the collection for id 101 in ALL subdocuments **with** type Manager.  (2) If 101 exists in a **"Manager"** subdocument, I want to remove item 103.

I have been pouring over the interwebs for two days on this issue and cannot figure it out.

I've tried this (and many other variations):

```
db.workers.update( {"type":"Manager","employees.id":101},{$pull : {"employees.id" : {"id" : 103}}},false,true)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of your `$pull` object is off.  Try this instead:

```js
db.workers.update({"type":"Manager","employees.id":101},
    {$pull : {"employees" : {"id" : 103}}},false,true)
```

To confirm they were removed:

```js
db.workers.find({
    type: "Manager", 
    $and: [{'employees.id': 101}, {'employees.id': 103}]
})
```

Comment: I do this and then I do the following to verify this combination no  
longer exists:  
db.workers.find({"type":"Manager","items.id":101, "items.id":103}).count()
and I Still get 8 records found - is my find incorrect?

Comment: @user2249490 That query isn't valid.  You can't use the same key of `"items.id"` twice in the same query object.

Comment: Thank you. How would I write a query to verify that 103 and 101 no longer exist together in the same employees key?